# How to make github send cummulative comments for pull request?

Tags: github, pull-request

When commenting on code changes in github pull request it sends mail notification for every comment. Is there a way to make it wait and send all comments in one mail when I'm done with review?

Comment: I would love to know how to do this, I don't think it's possible from what I can see in the Github UI.  Maybe via their API.